# How to get the list of file paths for only pdf files

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to create a pdf viewer application. For this, I want to create a page that will show all the available directories and only pdf files those are available in those directories. But my code only displays The files those are available in Internal storage. It even does not show the option to go to the external storage path. And it does not filter my files with .pdf extensions instead it displays all of them those are available. The package I am using here for managing file path is [file_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/file_manager) package. I am new in this field please help me.

### Here is my code

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'HomePage.dart';

import 'package:file_manager/controller/file_manager_controller.dart';
import 'package:file_manager/file_manager.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// final FileManagerController controller = FileManagerController();

class FolderPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const FolderPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final FileManagerController controller = FileManagerController();
    return ControlBackButton(
      controller: controller,
      child: FileManager(
          controller: controller,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            List<FileSystemEntity> entities = snapshot;
            
            
               for (FileSystemEntity entity in await entities) {
                 Future<FileSystemEntityType> type =
                     FileSystemEntity.type(entity.path);
                 if (type == FileSystemEntityType.directory) {
                   entities.add(Directory(entity.path));
                 } else if (type == FileSystemEntityType.file &&
                     entity.path.endsWith('.pdf')) {
                   entities.add(File(entity.path));
                 } else {
                   entities.remove(entity.path);
                 }
               }
               
            

            return Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 3.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 35, 51, 75)),
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: entities.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    margin:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 4.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0)),
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.4)),
                    child: ListTile(
                        leading: CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 40, 58, 85),
                            child: FileManager.isFile(entities[index])
                                ? Icon(Icons.feed_outlined)
                                : Icon(
                                    Icons.folder,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  )),
                        title: Text(
                          FileManager.basename(entities[index]),
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        onTap: () {
                          if (FileManager.isDirectory(entities[index])) {
                            controller.openDirectory(
                                entities[index]); // open directory
                          } else {
                            // Perform file-related tasks.
                          }
                        }),
                  );
                },
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```